# Slicing on Datetime and also keep Rows where only NA is present

Tags: r

I have multiple Duplicates in my dataset, which I can't resolve only taking one parameter into account. So I have to slice multiple times.

Example Dataset:

```
DF <- data.frame(Object=c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D"),
                 Value = c(4,4,3,4,2,1,4,3,4,2),
                 Datetime = c("2022-01-19 10:01:00","2022-01-19 10:04:00","2022-01-19 10:01:00",NA,"2022-01-19 10:01:00","2022-01-19 10:01:00",NA,NA,"2022-01-19 10:01:00","2022-01-19 10:01:00"))
```

I group by the relevant variables (represented by `Object`) and first `slice_max` on the sum of not NA values per row (represented by `Value`). There are still duplicates left:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

DF %>% 
  mutate(Datetime=ymd_hms(Datetime)) %>% 
  group_by(Object) %>% 
  slice_max(Value)


# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   Object [4]
  Object Value Datetime           
  <chr>  <dbl> <dttm>             
1 A          4 2022-01-19 10:01:00
2 A          4 2022-01-19 10:04:00
3 B          4 NA                 
4 C          4 NA                 
5 D          4 2022-01-19 10:01:00
```

Afterwards I want to take a Datetime into account. I want to keep the row with the minimal datetime, but if there is no row within the group with present values (only NA) I still want to keep it. Slice_min removes groups where only NA values are present. Groups B and C are missing.

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   Object [2]
  Object Value Datetime           
  <chr>  <dbl> <dttm>             
1 A          4 2022-01-19 10:01:00
2 D          4 2022-01-19 10:01:00
```

How can I slice on a Datetime and keep rows of groups, where no value is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257933/14027466) a general approach using `filter` and the `|` operator is described. It works also on Datetimes.

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(Datetime=ymd_hms(Datetime)) %>% 
  group_by(Object) %>% 
  slice_max(Value) %>% 
  filter(Datetime == min(Datetime) | is.na(Dateime))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   Object [4]
  Object Value Datetime           
  <chr>  <dbl> <dttm>             
1 A          4 2022-01-19 10:01:00
2 B          4 NA                 
3 C          4 NA                 
4 D          4 2022-01-19 10:01:00
```

Important is the syntax of the filter argument. At the beginning I had a wrong syntax, missing the `Datetime==`, which left me with an error message suggesting, that the `|` operator does not work with datetime:

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(Datetime=ymd_hms(Datetime)) %>% 
  group_by(Object) %>% 
  slice_max(Value) %>% 
  filter(min(Datetime) | is.na(Datetime))

Fehler: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `min(Datetime) | is.na(Datetime)`.
x '|' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Object = "A".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```